# How to get host name of same network connected devices in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking

I have checked with MMLanScan library, hostname always nil.
https://github.com/mavris/MMLanScan

I need to get the same Wi-Fi network connected devices and host name of the devices.

The code used for getHostName From IP Address .

```
struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
struct addrinfo hints;
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_flags = AI_NUMERICHOST;
hints.ai_family = PF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = 0;

int errorStatus = getaddrinfo([ipAddress cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], NULL, &hints, &result);
if (errorStatus != 0) {
    return nil;
}

CFDataRef addressRef = CFDataCreate(NULL, (UInt8 *)result->ai_addr, result->ai_addrlen);
if (addressRef == nil) {
    return nil;
}
freeaddrinfo(result);

CFHostRef hostRef = CFHostCreateWithAddress(kCFAllocatorDefault, addressRef);
if (hostRef == nil) {
    return nil;
}
CFRelease(addressRef);

BOOL succeeded = CFHostStartInfoResolution(hostRef, kCFHostNames, NULL);
if (!succeeded) {
    return nil;
}

NSMutableArray *hostnames = [NSMutableArray array];

CFArrayRef hostnamesRef = CFHostGetNames(hostRef, NULL);
for (int currentIndex = 0; currentIndex < [(__bridge NSArray *)hostnamesRef count]; currentIndex++) {
    [hostnames addObject:[(__bridge NSArray *)hostnamesRef objectAtIndex:currentIndex]];
}
NSLog(@"IP : %@",ipAddress);
NSLog(@"host name ; %@",hostnames);

return hostnames[0];
```

Comment: You can only get device names if there is a reverse ip->host mapping set up in DNS. In 99.9% of networks there will not be such records in DNS.